# Water flow at the normal to a face

Tags: normals, fluid-simulation, mantaflow

I want to make liquid flow out of a face of an object with the water flowing at the normal to the face. I've included an image demonstrating how I want this to work. I'm pretty inexperienced so if you guide me through this more detailed, that would be great.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd> - <kbd>A</kbd> -> Mesh -> Cylinder
2. <kbd>R</kbd> -> <kbd>X</kbd> -> 90

[image]

3. <kbd>S</kbd> -> <kbd>Y</kbd> -> <kbd>3</kbd>

[image]

4. Object -> Quick Effects -> Liquid

[image]

5. change flow behavior from geometry to inflow

[image]

6. check "Initial velocity" -> y: 20

[image]

7. Select Cylinder -> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> -> <kbd>S</kbd> -> 1.1

[image]

8. <kbd>Tab</kbd> -> Select top face

[image]

9. <kbd>X</kbd> -> delete face
10. <kbd>Tab</kbd>
11. Change type to effector

[image]

12. add solidify modifier, thickness: 0.1 -> move to top (before fluid)

[image]

13. select domain and press <kbd>S</kbd> -> 2 to double the size of the domain

[image]

14. change resolution division to 140

start animation by pressing <kbd>Space</kbd>

result:

[image]